# How to specify a default constructor as a parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

With the help of a StackOverflowee I have worked out how to specify a constructor as an argument to a class:

```
type GenericConstructor<T> = { new(): T; }

class MyClass<T> {
  subclass: T;
  constructor(
    SubClass: GenericConstructor<T>
  ) {
    this.subclass = new SubClass();
  }
}

class MySubClass1 { a = "" }

class MySubClass2 { b = "" }

const withSubClass1 = new MyClass(MySubClass1);
const withSubClass2 = new MyClass(MySubClass2);
```

If possible, I now wish to add a default `SubClass` so that users of `MyClass` are not forced to specify a subclass if the are happy with the default functionality.

Here's the code with what I had hoped would work (this does not work!):

```
type GenericConstructor<T> = { new(): T; }

class DefaultSubClass { c = "" }

class MyClass<T> {
  subclass: T;
  constructor(
    SubClass: GenericConstructor<T> = DefaultSubClass // <== error!!
  ) {
    this.subclass = new SubClass();
  }
}

// …snip
```

The error that TypeScript gives me is:

```
Type 'typeof DefaultSubClass' is not assignable to type 'GenericConstructor<T>'.
  Type 'DefaultSubClass' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'DefaultSubClass' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

Thanks for all the help as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be type-safe, because you're allowed to specify an explicit type argument. Imagine if someone called your constructor like this:

```js
let obj1: MyClass<MySubClass1> = new MyClass();
let obj2: MyClass<MySubClass2> = new MyClass();
```

Neither of these will be type errors, because the type parameter `T` can be inferred as `MySubClass1` in the first line and `MySubClass2` in the second line. In neither case will the object created actually satisfy the type annotation, but it's worse: even if you could make it work for one of them, you can't make it work for both, because the type arguments in the angle-brackets are erased at compile-time so there's no way to know at runtime which constructor to use.

A safe way to provide a default is to have a static factory method that isn't generic. This way, the caller can use `MyClass.create()` to create a class with the default subclass, but they can't also demand that `T` be something else.

```js
class MyClass<T> {
  static create(): MyClass<DefaultSubClass> {
    return new MyClass(DefaultSubClass);
  }

  subclass: T;
  constructor(
    SubClass: GenericConstructor<T>
  ) {
    this.subclass = new SubClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.  I was hoping to avoid a static constructor if possible but as you say it makes for a decent shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is really the behavior you want, there's two ways I can imagine doing it and neither is perfect.

---

The first is to use a [generic parameter default](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) for `T`:

```
class DefaultSubClass { c = "hey" }
class OtherSubClass { d = 123 };

class MyClass<T = DefaultSubClass> {
  subclass: T;
  constructor(
    SubClass?: new () => T
  );
  constructor(SubClass?: new () => any) {
    if (!SubClass) SubClass = DefaultSubClass;
    this.subclass = new SubClass();
  }
}

console.log(new MyClass().subclass.c.toUpperCase()); // HEY
console.log(new MyClass(OtherSubClass).subclass.d.toFixed(2)) // 123.00
```

This behaves as you like, although notice that I had to [overload](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) the constructor so the compiler doesn't (rightly) complain that it's not sure if `DefaultClass` will be assignable to `T`.

It's probably the simplest solution.

The downside here is that someone can call the zero-argument constructor and manually specify the wrong `T`.

```
console.log(new MyClass<OtherSubClass>().subclass.d.toFixed(2)); // oops
```

---

If you want to prevent that, the other way is to weakly type your class constructor value and then assign it to a value with a stronger type; this will need a type assertion to avoid compiler errors.  It's almost like writing your constructor in pure JavaScript and then later using TypeScript as a library to `declare` a strong type for it:

```
class _MyClass {
  subclass: any;
  constructor(ctor: new () => any = DefaultSubClass) {
    this.subclass = new ctor();
  }
}
```

That's your actual constructor value.  And here are the types we'd like for it to have:

```
interface MyClass<T> {
  subclass: T;
}
interface MyClassCtor {
  new(): MyClass<DefaultSubClass>;
  new <T>(ctor: new () => T): MyClass<T>;
}
```

You can see how `MyClassCtor` has two constructor signatures; the zero-arg version *only* creates a `MyClass<DefaultSubClass>`, while the one-arg version creates a `MyClass<T>` for the appropriate `T`.  Then we assign the constructor value to a variable of the constructor type:

```
const MyClass = _MyClass as MyClassCtor;
```

Then the following still behaves as you want

```
console.log(new MyClass().subclass.c.toUpperCase()); // HEY
console.log(new MyClass(OtherSubClass).subclass.d.toFixed(2)) // 123.00
```

And now this is prohibited:

```
new MyClass<OtherSubClass>(); // error! wrong number of arguments
```

It's too bad this requires the complication of renaming `MyClass` out of the way and then asserting a type.  The reason you can't just do this directly is because of the [restriction on having a type parameter on constructor declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10860).  So while the type of `MyClassCtor` is possible to write, it's not directly implementable.  Oh well.

---

Okay, hope one of those will help you.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARCAzEBXANgFyQG8BYAKDKSXhxCilQ23wGUsAjAYRrqKqQF4kAIgAWEAJ5CkAXwpVu9APJ4xAJ1acFvACYCkARgBMAZhkBuMnOq16AWXFcbAHgAqetJlx4NjugD4iOUoodms6AC4kFwtSSkp4AHtgKDxVLHg8BNUACiC4nwUAfkjgCAB3JGyASgEAlzyqmLiqJJS0jKzsgptipFKK6tqkEGBxGpJY5qQAS3RKgEJuuhql+kEPJm92XygmqZVpqAA6ELYwtb7ypFXqvcpZSYerVoScCCOcBIBzbP6kex21ROoQUR3gR0yAFUYDAIKoOLQINVGkgAPSopAACQAogBNZ7JV7vT4-P4AhTZZRqVZVYFnUHaCEJABi0wAHhBtNlDFUauiDCYjgAGIUEqBEj7fX5XcnOKlw1Z+IGnc5HRmZVkcrk8lH8hIJGBQSykJ6kUCQWAIZBoayqEB4aZJQLkSbnBieFjbLSEPiCUQSKSm+JaAD6sp4E2aKoUkRG4juLWSqXSmRyHVUJSug34ATj7kYXhpzqmSAOx2jNj0f3TtzyD3uxso02AeDhmEQ-wcClcAUjcQrESie3rMxbbatnZ2HFTxbi-WqkXDUCcG0LXpsfgTfx72XTmYGNRzUSqi67zhcm7kI8SScnWkEYbPPFod5s06yMUb8kr8vU64jSC6IIRimNIn6ui8bySqSMpPlAyogjYYJMtCsLwoiyJmGiGI4viEGElBJLShUS6UioCr-lAtIDsc6osuynLcry2ECsYwqii6lBknBTi-oqtwsXCqhZPMSBlMJwBfH0WBgGwcJIAkcwgKoXwyRALZGi60hAA)